# Gstreamer sink play always goes full screen

Tags: raspbian

I have following command running in my sink side of gstreamer running in raspberry pi 2.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,enconding-name=H264" port = 5000 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink caps = "disp-width=160, disp-height=120"
```

But still, I have fullscreen video display whatever video frame size I send from source.

Please help. I would like to have 1:1 frame size as I sent from source.